# Can I use the data from my Resource.Schema.Mof file in a powershell script?

Tags: powershell, dry, dsc

I'm working on writing a DSC resource for managing Windows DNS configuration items (BootMethod, EventLogLevel, etc.). My `Get-TargetResource` function needs to iterate over all of the configuration items that the resource will be able to manage. Currently, I've got a hashtable in the `Resource.psm1` file describing all of these, but I'd like to be able to use the description that already exists in the `Resource.Schema.Mof` file, which is required to build a resource in the first place. Is this possible, or possibly ill-advised for some reason I'm not aware of?

Schema.mof:

```
[ClassVersion("1.0.0"), FriendlyName("GO_DnsServerConfig")]
class GO_DnsServerConfig : OMI_BaseResource
{
[Key] string Name;
[Write,ValueMap{"Present","Absent"},Values{"Present","Absent"}]
string Ensure;
[Write] UInt32 AddressAnswerLimit;
[Write,ValueMap{"0","1"},Values{"0","1"}] UInt32 BindSecondaries;
[Write,ValueMap{"0","1","2","3"},Values{"0","1","2","3"}]
UInt32 BootMethod;
[Write,ValueMap{"0","1"},Values{"0","1"}] UInt32 DefaultAgingState;
[Write] UInt32 DefaultNoRefreshInterval;
[Write] UInt32 DefaultRefreshInterval;
[Write,ValueMap{"0","1"},Values{"0","1"}] UInt32 DisableAutoReverseZones;
[Write,ValueMap{"0","1"},Values{"0","1"}]
UInt32 DisableNsRecordsAutoCreation;
[Write] UInt32 DsPollingInterval;
[Write] UInt32 DsTombstoneInterval;
[Write] UInt32 EDnsCacheTimeout;
/* Does not appear to be fully implemented in dnscmd
[Write,ValueMap{"0","1"},Values{"0","1"}] UInt32 EnableDnsProbes;
*/
[Write,ValueMap{"0","1"},Values{"0","1"}] UInt32 EnableDnsSec;
[Write,ValueMap{"0","1"},Values{"0","1"}]
UInt32 EnableGlobalNamesSupport;
[Write,ValueMap{"0","1"},Values{"0","1"}]
UInt32 EnableGlobalQueryBlocklist;
[Write,ValueMap{"0","1","2","4"},Values{"0","1","2","4"}]
UInt32 EventLogLevel;
[Write,ValueMap{"0","1"},Values{"0","1"}] UInt32 ForwardDelegations;
[Write] UInt32 ForwardingTimeout;
[Write,ValueMap{"0","1"},Values{"0","1"}] UInt32 GlobalNamesQueryOrder;
/*
[Read,ValueMap{"isatap","wpad"},Values{"isatap","wpad"}]
String GlobalQueryBlocklist;
*/
[Write,ValueMap{"0","1"},Values{"0","1"}] UInt32 IsSlave;
[Write,ValueMap{"0","1"},Values{"0","1"}] UInt32 LocalNetPriority;
[Write] UInt32 LogFileMaxSize;
[Write] string LogFilePath;
[Write] string LogIpFilterList;
[Write] uint32 LogLevel;
[Write] uint64 MaxCacheSize;
[Write]
uint32 MaxCacheTtl;
[Write,ValueMap{"0","1","2","3"},Values{"0","1","2","3"}]
uint16 NameCheckFlag;
[Write,ValueMap{"0","1"},Values{"0","1"}] UInt32 NoRecursion;
[Write] uint32 RecursionRetry;
[Write] uint32 RecursionTimeout;
[Write,ValueMap{"0","1"},Values{"0","1"}] UInt32 RoundRobin;
[Write] uint32 RpcProtocol;
[Write] uint32 ScavengingInterval;
[Write,ValueMap{"0","1"},Values{"0","1"}] UInt32 SecureResponses;
[Write] uint32 SendPort;
[Write] string ServerLevelPluginDll;
[Write,ValueMap{"0","1"},Values{"0","1"}] UInt32 StrictFileParsing;
[Write] UInt32 UpdateOptions;
[Write,ValueMap{"0","1"},Values{"0","1"}] UInt32 WriteAuthorityNs;
[Write] uint32 XfrConnectTimeout;
};
```

Get-TargetResource function:

```
function Get-TargetResource
{
[CmdletBinding()]
[OutputType([Hashtable])]
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$Name
)

Set-StrictMode -Version 2.0
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

$ConfigItems =
@{
    Name                         = $Name;
    Ensure                       = $null;
    AddressAnswerLimit           = $null;
    BindSecondaries              = $null;
    BootMethod                   = $null;
    DefaultAgingState            = $null;
    DefaultNoRefreshInterval     = $null;
    DefaultRefreshInterval       = $null;
    DisableAutoReverseZones      = $null;
    DisableNsRecordsAutoCreation = $null;
    DsPollingInterval            = $null;
    DsTombstoneInterval          = $null;
    EDnsCacheTimeout             = $null;
    #EnableDnsProbes              = $null; #Disabled; see schema.
    EnableDnsSec                 = $null;
    EnableGlobalNamesSupport     = $null;
    EnableGlobalQueryBlocklist   = $null;
    EventLogLevel                = $null;
    ForwardDelegations           = $null;
    ForwardingTimeout            = $null;
    GlobalNamesQueryOrder        = $null;
    GlobalQueryBlocklist         = $null;
    IsSlave                      = $null;
    LocalNetPriority             = $null;
    LogFileMaxSize               = $null;
    LogFilePath                  = $null;
    LogIpFilterList              = $null;
    LogLevel                     = $null;
    MaxCacheSize                 = $null;
    MaxCacheTtl                  = $null;
    NameCheckFlag                = $null;
    NoRecursion                  = $null;
    RecursionRetry               = $null;
    RecursionTimeout             = $null;
    RoundRobin                   = $null;
    RpcProtocol                  = $null;
    ScavengingInterval           = $null;
    SecureResponses              = $null;
    SendPort                     = $null;
    ServerLevelPluginDll         = $null;
    StrictFileParsing            = $null;
    UpdateOptions                = $null;
    WriteAuthorityNs             = $null;
    XfrConnectTimeout            = $null;
}

Write-Verbose "Check to see if there is a DNS server present on the box."
$ConfigItems.Ensure = Get-EnsureValue
If ($ConfigItems.Ensure -eq 'Present')
{
    Write-Verbose "A DNS Server was found on this machine."
    $ConfigItems.Ensure = 'Present'

    Write-Verbose "Create a new hashtable to store the result."
    $result = @{}

    Write-Verbose "Add manually enumerated values to the resultset."
    $result.Add('Name', $ConfigItems.Name)
    $result.Add('Ensure', $ConfigItems.Ensure)

    Write-Verbose "Get the current value for any item that is null."
    $ConfigItems.GetEnumerator() `
    | Where-Object {$_.Value -eq $null} `
    | ForEach-Object `
    {
        $itemName = $_.Name
        Write-Verbose "Getting: '$itemName'"
        $itemValue =
            Get-DnsConfigurationItem -Item $itemName
        Write-Debug "Value: '$itemValue'"

        if ($itemValue -ne $null)
        {
            Write-Verbose "Adding item to resultset."
            $result.Add($itemName, $itemValue)
        }
    }
}
Else
{
    Write-Verbose "No DNS server was found on this machine."
    Write-Verbose "Returning with Ensure = '$($ConfigItems.Ensure)'."
    $result = @{ Name = $ConfigItems.Name; Ensure = $ConfigItems.Ensure }
}

return $result
}
```

Comment: Could you post your module code, or a snippet of it, and the relevant section of the MOF?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm having trouble finding `the description that already exists in the Resource.Schema.Mof, and I'm not seeing where in your code you want to re-use that value. Could you point where you would be repeating the description, and where you;d like it to be defined once?

Comment: Everything in the Schema.mof file is being defined a second time in the $ConfigItems hashtable so that I can iterate over it and grab the real values. I'd like to be able to read the Schema.mof data in place of that hashtable.

Comment: Oh I think I see what you're saying now. Have you considered doing the reverse? Generate your MOF file based on script? [Have a look at this `New-MofFile` function](https://github.com/PowerShellOrg/DSC/blob/master/Tooling/DscDevelopment/New-MofFile.ps1).

Comment: Well, that would add a build step, which I'd rather avoid. It seems like there must be some functions in .Net for parsing .Mof files. I just don't know whether any of it is public.

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing the resource using classes which is being introduced in PowerShell v5. It should largely eliminate the problem that you are talking about - for one there is no schema.mof to being with